# Can't get onSnapshot to render once. It duplicates

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project with React and Firestore.

I'm working on a page which will read through multiple images and certain fields of these images will be changed. Once changes are made, i just want the one image doc to update rather than everything on the page hence onSnapshot.

The onSnapshot listener keeps adding on to the images that i have whenever changes are made. I understand that everytime useEffect is called it adds the same images but i don't know how to fix it. I have seen some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338834/why-is-onsnapshot-duplicating-my-records-in-react), but they don't cater to the IDs array which i need to reference a document when making changes to it.

```js
export default function Images({ user }) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [ids, setIDs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const colRef = collection(db, "images");
    const q = query(colRef, where("user", "==", user));

    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        setImages((prev) => [...prev, doc.data()]);
        setIDs((prev) => [...prev, doc.id]);
      });
    });
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <>
      {images && (
        <div className="m-4 grid grid-cols-2 grid-flow-row">
          {images.map((image, index) => {
            const imageID = ids[index];
            return <Labels image={image} imageID={imageID} />;
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that you're using `[...prev, doc.data()]` no? This will cause the array to keep adding up everytime snapshot changes.

Comment: Yes, i agree 100% but how do i fix it? I can't think of a better way but i know that there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the link you attached in your question: [Why is onSnapshot duplicating my records in REACT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338834/why-is-onsnapshot-duplicating-my-records-in-react) - The answer should be exactly what you want.

The issue here is that you're using `[...prev, doc.data()]` no? This will cause the array to keep adding up everytime snapshot changes.
What you can do instead is to map through the `snapshot.docs` and then get the results and set it as your state as such:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const colRef = collection(db, "images");
    const q = query(colRef, where("user", "==", user));

    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const docs = snapshot.docs;
      setIDs(docs.map(doc => doc.id);
      setImages(docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    });
  }, [user]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. Tell me about ```docs.map(doc=>doc.id)```, why does that compile all ids rather than overwrite the previous one with the latest one?

Comment: From what I know, in the snapshot, if you use look into `docs`, you will have the whole data basically. If you want only the changes, you can make use of `docChanges` instead. I can't really go in depth regarding this sorry, but you can read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen